# Symfony2 favicon does not show for IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, symfony, favicon

We are leading with a issue with favicon on Symfony2, It's no being showed on IE9. Here the code we're using:

```
   <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.png') }}">
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.png') }}">
    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}"><![endif]-->
```

the rest of browsers is showing it, but not for IE
any hint?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your `favicon.ico` file exists in the same folder where `favicon.png` is?

Comment: Yes, It does. Both of them are located on web/images

Comment: Cache flushed on both side (sf and browser), still happening

Comment: And if you use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) , do you see it being downloaded? Is your IE somehow running in compatibility mode?

Comment: We found out the reason, We are using https, but on qc environment we don have a signed certification, so that does not like to IE, we turn off for a moment secure-connection and the icon appears.

Answer (score -1):

IE only supports favicon in root.

Comment: It'S not wrong. My Answer may be unspecific, but IE up to version 7 does only support favicon.ico in root and does not look at rel="icon"!